# How can I open google map for a specific region

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map API to show our locations in a website

The problem:
I search something opening google.com and navigate to map, it is same as the locator on the website. It gives the same result.

When google is opened in local and navigate to map and do the same search, it will navigate to same place however the name is different. Please note it is not that name is in English and French that's the reason it is different. Basically this region on question is disputed over the countries.

Description:
When client opens google in his locale e.g. https://www.google.fr/ and navigates to google map he gets a different result, the name is different for the same place in google map as the place is in the border of 2 countries .
If you open by google.com it will show the widely accepted name whereas if you open google.xx and then open the same location the name will be different.

The locator by default is showing the global name in the website which the client does not want, he is asking for showing the name as displayed when opening from their region.

Is there a way I can set something like a data source or something to show google map based on some particular region.

Help will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Take look at [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics?hl=en#Region):you can add an optional language parameter to the <script> tag when including the Maps API JavaScript code, specifying the language to use.
For example, to display a Maps API application in Japanese, add `&language=ja` to the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really helpful for us.

Comment: Glad to help, cheers! I posted an answer for this, you can accept it if you feel that I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics?hl=en#Region).

You can add an optional language parameter to the `<script>` tag when including the Maps API JavaScript code, specifying the language to use. For example, to display a Maps API application in Japanese, add `&language=ja` to the `<script>` tag.